# How to save new state to local json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a local JSON file which is used for loading all data to app. In one component I load in `constructor()` those data. In function `addRow()` I add new field but it's just in local state variable. I would like to add it to json file also, so after refresh this new row will be still here.

I was trying find how this solved really easy but I didn't find it. If you know about some topic send it to me.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        employees: require('json!../../../data/employees.json')
    };
    this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
}

addEmployee(employee) {
    this.setState({
        employees: this.state.employees.concat([employee])
    });
}
```

Comment: POST request + server side script to write to json file.

Comment: Or some javascript (node.js) plugin for react which can work with json

Comment: No, you can't write files with just client side code, you need backend for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the file system from the browser for security reasons. If you just want to access it after refreshing, I guess that you could save it in localStorage when you modify the state and then use it when the component is loaded it if it's not undefined (you can check this in componentDidMount). (The code below is not tested)

```
addEmployee(employee) {
    let newEmployees = this.state.employees.concat([employee])
    localStorage.setItem('employees', JSON.stringify(newEmployees));
    this.setState({
        employees: newEmployees
    });
}


componentDidMount(){
     let newEmployees = localStorage.employees
     if(newEmployees != undefined){
         this.setState({
             employees: JSON.parse(newEmployees)
         });
     }
}
```

If you want to store that JSON persistently and you want more than being able to use it after refreshing, you should do it on the backend. You can also let the user save the file manually (with a download prompt) as it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329293/save-json-string-to-client-pc-using-html5-api).

Comment: Shoudn't be `if (localStorage.employees != undefined) {` instead `employees`

Comment: Plus while adding it gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: JSON.stringfy is not a function(…)`. Do I have to import some library for it ? I thought it's a built-in function.

Comment: Yes, it's newEmployees (or localStorage.employees) and stringify, I edited the answer, you should also parse the stringified JSON when you get it from localStorage.

Comment: Could you also help with that? I tried it this way. http://pastebin.com/sVqkLMAH. It gives me `map is not a function`

Comment: In the edited answer I already added the JSON.parse method to get the object back from the string so that you can use map directly with the object you get from the state :) `this.setState({
             employees: JSON.parse(newEmployees)
         });`

Comment: With this setting `addEmployee()` doesn't work and it gives me followin error `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.employees.map is not a function`

Comment: Did you try using console.log(this.state.employees) to see its value? If it's an array it should work.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it's array. I don't understand why it's happened, because this `map()` use only for create rows in table. And this problem it's called when I try to add new user.

Comment: Is the data formatted with {} or []? This is likely to be a formatting issue of some kind. [This answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142361/react-js-uncaught-typeerror-this-props-data-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: In chrome console it's `[Object, Object, ...]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127195/discussion-between-mardzis-and-cesar-landesa).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it from the client/browser, since they do not have access to file system (form security considerations). You'll to do it on the backend.