# Chrome stops download files from StackOverflow snippets

Tags: javascript

In MacOs (HighSierra) on Chrome 83.0 yesterday following code, after run as StackOverflow snippet, automatically download file `myFile.json` (try yourself)

```js
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "data:application/octet-stream,"+encodeURIComponent('"My DATA"');
a.download = 'myFile.json';
a.click();
```

Today it stops working. I totally don't know why. I check this code on Safari and Firefox - and it works. For Edge (which use chrome under the hood) it not works. JSFiddle version works on Chrome and Edge - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/0pds6t3b/). So the problem appear only on Chrome (and Edge) only for StackOverflow site. Today I go to chrome-console>Application and clean all stackoverflow storage/cookies - not helps.

**Question**: Do you can reproduce it and do you have any suggestion what happen and how to fix this?

Comment: @SamiHaddad please write your comment as answer to this question - I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Chrome 83:

> Chrome is going to block all downloads initiated from or instantiated in a sandboxed iframe by default. The embedder may add "allow-downloads" to the sandbox attributes list to opt in. This allows content providers to restrict malicious or abusive downloads.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280