# How to download a json file which is coming from odata service in sapui5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I need to download a JSON file from **OData service** by pressing a button in **SAPUI5**. For example, the path is "/abcd()" and the file is a base 64-encoded JSON. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could let me know how to consume it and download it as a plain text/JSON format. Thanks in advance. Please help.

I am trying to do like:

**For XML:**

```
<form:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            width="30rem"
            editable="true"
            visible="{model>/download}">
            <form:toolbar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Title id="idTitle"
                        text="{i18n>title}" />
                </Toolbar>
            </form:toolbar>
            <Button id="idDownload"
                text="Download"
                press="onDataDownload" />
        </form:SimpleForm>
```

**For JS:**

```
onDataDownload: function () {
            return model.getInstance().getOdataWrapper().getEntitySet({
                path: "/abcd"
            }).then((res) => {
                const blob = new Blob([res], { type: "application/json" });
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "filename");
                } else {
                    const ele = window.document.createElement("a");
                    ele.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    ele.download = "filename";
                    document.body.appendChild(ele);
                    ele.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(ele);
                }
            });
       }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save json string to client pc (using HTML5 API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329293/save-json-string-to-client-pc-using-html5-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue.

```
onDataDownload: function () {
            //call the function
            let obj = model.getInstance().getModelService().bindContext("/abcd(...)", undefined, {
                $$updateGroupId: "anyName"
            });

            obj.execute("anyName").then(function () {
                var encoded = obj.getBoundContext().getObject().value;
                var decoded = atob(encoded);
                const blob = new Blob([decoded], { type: "application/json" });

                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "ABCD.json");
                    
                } else {
                    const ele = window.document.createElement("a");
                    ele.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    ele.download = "ABCD.json";
                    document.body.appendChild(ele);
                    ele.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(ele);
                    
                }
    
            });
            model.getInstance().getModelService().submitBatch("anyName");
        }
```